# Triple relation lookup in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have tried to solve this one but its WAY over my Mongo skill level.
I hope there are some hardcore Mongo wizards who have an idea :-)

I would like to make a result where

```
db.getCollection('invoice').find({
        dueDate: {
            $gte:148000000,
            $lt: 149000000
        }        
})
```

This is the "invoice" table....

```
invoice
{
    "_id" : "KLKIU",
    "invoiceNumber" : 1,
    "bookingId" : "0J0DR",
    "dueDate" : "148100000",
    "account" : "aaaaaaaaaa",
    "invoiceLines" : [ 
        {
            "lineText" : "Booking fee",
            "amount" : 1000
        }, 
        {
            "lineText" : "Discount",
            "amount" : -200
        }, 
        {
            "lineText" : "Whatever extra",
            "amount" : 400
        }
    ]
}
```

this is the result

```
{
    "_id" : "KLKIU",
    "invoiceNumber" : 1,
    "bookingId" : "0J0DR",
    "dueDate" : "148100000",
    "account" : "aaaaaaaaaa",
    "invoiceLines" : [ 
        {
            "lineText" : "Booking fee",
            "amount" : 1000
        }, 
        {
            "lineText" : "Discount",
            "amount" : -200
        }, 
        {
            "lineText" : "Whatever extra",
            "amount" : 400
        }
    ], 
    "propertyName" : "Atlantis Condo",
}
```

please notice the "propertyName" at the bottom

it needs to lookup and add 
    "propertyName" : "Atlantis Condo",
which will be done like this

```
db.getCollection('booking').find({
    booking._id: invoice.bookingId
})
```

and then

```
db.getCollection('property').find({
    property._id: booking:propertyId 
})
```

These are the two tables:

```
Booking
{
    "_id" : "0J0DR",
    "propertyId" : "58669471869659d70b424ea7",
}

Property
{
    "_id" : "58669471869659d70b424ea7",
    "propertyName" : "Atlantis Condo",
}
```

Hope someone can figure this out - right now im doing some horrible sequential loops, and with big amounts of data thats really slow.

Comment: What is your mongo version ? And all are relations one to one ?

Comment: @Veeram - I have the newest Mongo version 3.4 - and yes relations are one to one.

Comment: meaning booking._id is unique and property._id is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

`$lookup`'s to join to `Booking` and `Property` collection.

`$unwind` to flatten the `booking` array output from `$lookup` for joining on local field to `Property` collection.

`$addFields` to project the `propertyName` field.

`$project` to exclude the fields from referenced collection.

```
db.getCollection('invoice').aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "dueDate": {
            $gte: 148000000,
            $lt: 149000000
        }
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "Booking",
        localField: "bookingId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "booking"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$booking"
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "Property",
        localField: "booking.propertyId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "property"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$property"
}, {
    $addFields: {
        "propertyName": "$property.propertyName"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "booking": 0
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "property": 0
    }
}])
```

Comment: thank you so much!! I just learned a lot there - didnt even know the $project command.   

I got another problem thou, 

db.getCollection('invoice').aggregate([{

 dueDate : {$gte: ("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt: ("2017-03-01T00:00:00.000Z")}
 
}])

This gives me 

assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'dueDate'",
 "code" : 16436
} : aggregate failed

(and btw my mongodb server version is 3.2.12  -  is that the reason you think?, would an upgrade solve the problem?)

Comment: You are welcome.I have already updated the answer for that issue. It was missing `$match`. The code is not going to work if you are on 3.2.12. If you have a opportunity please upgrade. `$addFields` stage is only available in 3.4

Comment: ".find" works great but ".aggregate" gives the "Unrecognized pipeline stage name"

Comment: Ahh okie - thanks - I will upgrade when the sysadm is there tomorrow :)

Comment: Once again - thanks a bunch Veeram - everything worked perfectly!! And this taught me to optimize a lot of my other gets :-)